# The right way to write variable in Qt pro file?

Tags: qmake

For example, a variable is declared as `TEST_VAR`.

```
1. $TEST_VAR
2. $(TEST_VAR)
3. ${TEST_VAR}
4. $$TEST_VAR
5. $$(TEST_VAR)
6. $${TEST_VAR}
```

What the right way to use it in the `.pro` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qmake is an interpretator, so it doesn't have explicit variable declarations.

Qmake's assignment operator has a form of "variable = string", so, say `X = Y` is interpreted as "the variable named X is assigned with *a string* "Y"". To produce *a (string) value* of a variable an operator `$$` is needed: `X = $$Y`.

The operator `$$` has two forms: `$$Y` and `$${Y}`. Both are equivalent, except the latter allows pasting variable's value with another string. For example, `X = $$YZ` means "X is assigned with the value of a variable named YZ", while `X = $${Y}Z` means "X is assigned with the value of a variable named Y pasted with a string literal "Z"".

Qmake also has a few other expansion syntaxes intended to address "variables" from outside of a current .pro file:

- `$$(var)` is a value of an [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) of qmake process;
- `$(var)` is a value of an [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) of make process;
- `$$[var]` is a value of a so-called "property", i.e. a system-wide variable managed by qmake itself (see [QSettings](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html)::NativeFormat).

Answer (score 1):

The proper syntax would be: `$$TEST_VAR` or `$${TEST_VAR}`

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-language.html#variable-expansion
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-language.html#variables